# How to pull the data from remote database in Apache Kafka?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to make real-time data pipeline in Apache Kafka. I have database which is located at remote location and that database continuously updating. Can anybody which Kafka connect API i should use to pull the data from database and ingest into Kafka broker in real time? later on i would use kafka stream and KSQL to run ad-hoc queries to perform the metrics.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but "database" is far too vague. Can you clarify? Which Kafka Connects have you found and tried? What errors do you get when trying to run them?

Comment: If your data base is a relational database of hdfs you can make use of confluents bundled connectors. 
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connectors.html

If you have some other database you need to develop your own kafka connect plugin:
https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html

Comment: I have MYSQL database which is at remote location i have ip, host id etc. I don't understand which connector i should use to pull the data from mysql to kafka and database is continuously updating. I am trying to make real time data pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a real-time data pipeline you need to use a Change Data Capture (CDC) tool which is able to stream changes from MySQL. I would suggest [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) which is an open source distributed platform for change data capture.

**Capturing Inserts**

When a new record is added to a table, a JSON similar to the one below will be produced:

```
{  
   "payload":{  
      "before":null,
      "after":{  
         "id":1005,
         "first_name":"Giorgos",
         "last_name":"Myrianthous",
         "email":"giorgos@abc.com"
      },
      "source":{  
         "name":"dbserver1",
         "server_id":223344,
         "ts_sec":1500369632,
         "gtid":null,
         "file":"mysql-bin.000003",
         "pos":364,
         "row":0,
         "snapshot":null,
         "thread":13,
         "db":"inventory",
         "table":"customers"
      },
      "op":"c",
      "ts_ms":1500369632095
   }
}
```

`before` object is null and `after` object contains the newly inserted values. Note that the `op` attribute is `c`, indicating that this was a CREATE event.

**Capturing Updates**

Assuming that `email` attribute has been updated, a JSON similar to the one below will be produced:

```
{ 
    "payload":{  
      "before":{  
         "id":1005,
         "first_name":"Giorgos",
         "last_name":"Myrianthous",
         "email":"giorgos@abc.com"
      },
      "after":{  
         "id":1005,
         "first_name":"Giorgos",
         "last_name":"Myrianthous",
         "email":"newEmail@abc.com"
      },
      "source":{  
         "name":"dbserver1",
         "server_id":223344,
         "ts_sec":1500369929,
         "gtid":null,
         "file":"mysql-bin.000003",
         "pos":673,
         "row":0,
         "snapshot":null,
         "thread":13,
         "db":"inventory",
         "table":"customers"
      },
      "op":"u",
      "ts_ms":1500369929464
   }
}
```

Notice `op` which is now `u`, indicating that this was an UPDATE event. `before` object shows the row state before the update and `after` object captures the current state of the updated row.

**Capturing deletes**

Now assume that the row has been deleted;

```
{ 
    "payload":{  
      "before":{  
         "id":1005,
         "first_name":"Giorgos",
         "last_name":"Myrianthous",
         "email":"newEmail@abc.com"
      },
      "after":null,
      "source":{  
         "name":"dbserver1",
         "server_id":223344,
         "ts_sec":1500370394,
         "gtid":null,
         "file":"mysql-bin.000003",
         "pos":1025,
         "row":0,
         "snapshot":null,
         "thread":13,
         "db":"inventory",
         "table":"customers"
      },
      "op":"d",
      "ts_ms":1500370394589
   }
}
```

`op` new is equal to  `d`, indicating a DELETE event. `after` attribute will be null and `before` object contains the row before it gets deleted.

You can also have a look at the [extensive tutorial](https://debezium.io/docs/tutorial/) provided in their website.

**EDIT:** [Example configuration](https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#example-configuration) for a MySQL database

```
{
  "name": "inventory-connector",  (1)
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", (2)
    "database.hostname": "192.168.99.100", (3)
    "database.port": "3306", (4)
    "database.user": "debezium", (5)
    "database.password": "dbz", (6)
    "database.server.id": "184054", (7)
    "database.server.name": "fullfillment", (8)
    "database.whitelist": "inventory", (9)
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", (10)
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.fullfillment" (11)
    "include.schema.changes": "true" (12)
  }
}
```

> 1 The name of our connector when we register it with a Kafka Connect
>   service. 
>   2 The name of this MySQL connector class. 
> 3   The address of
>   the MySQL server. 
> 4   The port number of the MySQL server. 
> 5  The name of
>   the MySQL user that has the required privileges. 
> 6    The password for
>   the MySQL user that has the required privileges. 
> 7    The connector’s
>   identifier that must be unique within the MySQL cluster and similar to
>   MySQL’s server-id configuration property. 
> 8   The logical name of the
>   MySQL server/cluster, which forms a namespace and is used in all the
>   names of the Kafka topics to which the connector writes, the Kafka
>   Connect schema names, and the namespaces of the corresponding Avro
>   schema when the Avro Connector is used. 
> 9 A list of all databases
>   hosted by this server that this connector will monitor. This is
>   optional, and there are other properties for listing the databases and
>   tables to include or exclude from monitoring. 
> 10  The list of Kafka
>   brokers that this connector will use to write and recover DDL
>   statements to the database history topic. 
> 11  The name of the database
>   history topic where the connector will write and recover DDL
>   statements. This topic is for internal use only and should not be used
>   by consumers. 
> 12  The flag specifying that the connector should
>   generate on the schema change topic named fullfillment events with the
>   DDL changes that can be used by consumers.

Comment: I have read it just wanted to know where do i need to mention remote database credential most of bloggers have shown example with local database.

Comment: @PSP Instead of `localhost` simply use the ip you want to.

Comment: @PSP I've edited my answer to include an example configuration for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from a MySQL database use Confluent's JDBC Source connector. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/
You'll also need to download the MYSQL driver and put it with the kafka jars: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Comment: can you share the sample code so that i can get the more clarity. I am still wondering where do i need to configure remote db credential like host name, IP, username, password etc.