# How to pull data from amazon EC2 instance using Confluent Kafka JDBC source connector?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have confluent platform on my local machine i am just trying to read the data from aws ec2 instance i have credentials like hostname, DB name, pwd etc. I am using JDBC source connector. connector config is

```
name=test
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector 
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://ab.bca.bdc.aaa:abcd/DB?user=abc&password=bca
table.whitelist=ppp
mode=incrementing
```

after running connect standalone got error like

```
Invalid value java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the connection string near
```

Comment: Try using another JDBC tool with that exact same connection string... `Malformed database URL` is not a Kafka Connect problem

Comment: could you elaborate i didn't understand. using mysql connector version 8.

Comment: I'm not talking about the version. The error very clearly states that the URL is malformed, which is not a problem that can be fixed alone by Kafka Connect. If you copied the exact same URL into some other Java code that uses JDBC, you should expect to see the same errors, which is what I'm asking you to try

Answer (score 0):

According to [the JDBC MySQL syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html), user and password go before the database address as colon separated, not after

`user:password@host_or_host_sublist`

Not sure if using RDS or your own EC2 database would change the syntax of that

If you want to capture all database events, though, [Debezium (your old question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52090332/2308683) would be what you want. Using the JDBC connector won't capture deletes (or events created and deleted between polls) and puts unnecessary strain on your database